# VBA Update MS Access Database - Multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to update my db based on multiple conditions.
(I have a set of columns in excel retrieved out of the same database)

The code below works fine if I have one "WHERE condition". If I add multiple "AND" conditions, it doesn't update the db. Guessing it's a syntax problem in my sql statement.

**Working Code**

```
Dim dbione, dbitwo, dbithree, stime As String
Set r = [B3]
While r.Offset(0, -1).Value > 0
dbione = r.Offset(0, 0) 'this is an ID
dbitwo = r.Offset(0, 1) 'this is another ID
dbithree = r.Offset(0, 2) 'this is another ID

stime = r.Offset(0, 4)
```

Appreciate anyone helping to fix this for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think posting my question here jogged my thinking. I was able to solve this as soon as i posted :) 
the issue was with the -1 as the column was blank!
corrected this bit and it works fine:
    `r.Offset(0, -1).Value > 0`